# Rejection: “2.23: Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines”

Tags: ios, iphone

I have been facing a strange problem
out app has just been rejected by Apple for the reason “2.23: Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines”
And then we move the data stored in "Documents" to "Library/Cache"
after that, the Document directory is empty(check from itunes)
but, in icloud, there are still 0.4 KB? (I did remove my app, delete backup from icloud first)
Any idea? or suggestion?, how do I find out the files to remove?
thanks.

[Question Modify]
My question look like too similar to another.
My major problem is the ghost 0.4KB, I can't find where is it, and I am pretty sure that I didn't create that. And can't find anyone point that will cause another rejection or not?
So, I need somebody to share some experience or advice, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you receive this rejection notice, the review team point you to [this Technical Q&A page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html) which describes how to exclude a file from being backed up.

For convenience, this is the example function that they provide to set this property:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}
```

Additionally, [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28) describes where you should put your data - for example, data that can be created by your app should be placed in `/Library/Application Support`, and user-created data should be placed in `Documents`.

If you have placed your data in `/Library/Caches`, it will not be backed up by iTunes/iCloud, however you should reconsider if this is the correct place to put the data that you moved. If you moved it simply to stop it from being backed up, this is probably incorrect - place it in the correct folder and set the "don't back up" key as described above. Apple notes that "the system may delete the Caches/ directory to free up disk space".

Comment: Sorry, too late to edit. I will modify my solution. I have set Documents to be skip already. But, I have something confuse, 1.I don't need to keep any thing to be backup, so can I skip whole the Documents directory? 2.I can't find where is the 0.4KB(but I just figure out it comes from GoogleMap SDK), does it matter? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Onader.Wu `Documents` should be for user-generated content. `Application Support` should be for data that your app needs to run, whether or not it needs to be backed up. `Caches` should be for data that can be recreated, because it might be deleted. 0.4KB shouldn't matter - I assume your app was rejected before you made these changes? If your app doesn't create any backed-up files and it still shows as 0.4KB, I wouldn't worry about it - other rejection notices online seem to quote "2MB" as the limit.

Comment: Yes, it rejected before my modification. I will follow the suggestion to modify my app, thanks for your help.